# Is Bitmap threadsafe for readonly?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, task

I got `Collection` of `Bitmap` objects.
In need to create mutiple `Tasks`, pass this `Collection` as argument. In task method i will read height/width of each `Bitmap`, then send this `Collection` and height/width array  to Wcf service.

So is it threadsafe operation? How should i act in this case?

Comment: you have to send the array of heigh and width to your WCF service ?

Comment: Personally, after reading that brief description, I'd just use PLINQ to process the collection and then send the results. As long as you're not sharing mutable state, it should be OK.

Comment: Hardly seems worth a task to be honest.

Comment: @Dhaval Patel, its part of complicated data packs, its not my service and i cant change this DataContracts.

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson it worth it, coz after  i send this data to service it takes like 10-30 seconds before service give answer for some reasons so i dont wanna wait like 20 image-sends x 30 seconds. Each service (there about 20 of them) represent remote device with own logic and time to complete operation and return answer.

Comment: are you using .net 4.5?

Comment: @Dhaval Patel, no i forced to use .net 4.0

Comment: Now I'm confused, communicating with your service is one thing, prepping an array as the argument to the service is something entirely...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not, Bitmap doesn't behave much like a "normal" object at all.  Many operations on a Bitmap object involve an underlying call to Bitmap.LockBits().  Simple things you'd do, like calling the Save() method or drawing the bitmap with Graphics.DrawImage() or the infamously slow GetPixel() method need to lock the bitmap to get access to a memory-mapped view of the pixel data.

You may recognize the terminology, the same low-level operating system feature is exposed in the .NET Framework by the MemoryMappedFile class.  Important for bitmaps, they can contain a huge amount of data.  By using an MMF, that pixel data can be kept out of the paging file and page-faulted back into RAM from the image file.

This has many side-effects, it for example explains the common problem that programmers run into when they discover that the image file is locked and cannot be overwritten.  The MMF imposes that lock.  And a hard constraint is that a bitmap can be locked only once.  Or in other words, only one non-trivial operation on the Bitmap object can occur at the same time.  Your code is therefore liable to randomly crash when another worker thread tries to do something with the same bitmap object and you don't add the synchronization required to prevent this from happening.