# Bitmap.Save is throwing Invalid Parameter

Tags: c#, multithreading, bitmap, gdi, system.drawing

When passing a `Bitmap` to a method using `thread.Start()` and later calling `bitmap.save()` it throws the exception `Invalid parameter` when trying to save it to memory stream. I'm using a WPF project with .NET Framework 4.7.2.

```cs
private void StartBtn_Click()
{
    //is another class which accesses the stream of an external camera
    backEnd = new BackEnd();

    backEnd.ImageReceived += backEnd_ImageReceived;

    if (backEnd.Start())
    {
        hasError = false;
    }
    else
    {
        hasError = true;
    }
}

//is called when backEnd gets an image
private void backEnd_ImageReceived(object sender, Bitmap bitmap)
{
    try
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        bitmap.Save(memoryStream , System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        BitmapImage bitmapimage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapimage.BeginInit();
        bitmapimage.StreamSource = memoryStream ;
        bitmapimage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmapimage.EndInit();
        bitmapimage.Freeze();

        if (_otherThread == null)
        {
            _otherThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ProcessImage));
            _otherThread.Start(bitmap);
        }
        else if (!_otherThread.IsAlive)
        {
            _otherThread.Start(bitmap);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("--- [MainWindow] Exception: " + e.Message);
        backEnd_MessageBoxTrigger(this, "Exception", e.Message);
    }
}

//this method could take longer that's why I'm using a second thread
private void ProcessImage(object parameter)
{
    if (parameter.GetType() == typeof(Bitmap))
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = parameter as Bitmap;

        byte[] bytes;
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Throws invalid parameter exception
            bitmap.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

The `Invalid parameter exception`
[image: Screenshot of Invalid parameter exception]

When debugging and looking at the properties of the `bitmap` all properties show a `System Argument Exception`. [image: Screenshot of System Argument Exceptions]

Comment: Where is `memory` defined?

Comment: @Fildor ```memory``` is a global field

Comment: Which you initialize _after_ starting the backend operation that will be using it _and_ in oblivity of whether a previous invokation of the click handler is still using it... I am not saying that is your issue, but it surely contributes.

Comment: After edit: That did not improve a thing. You are still initializing the global field after starting the operation. Better try to not have that global field at all.

Comment: Can you add the "Invalid Parameter" Exception? The exceptions in the debug window may be only happening because of the first one.

Comment: Ah, so `bitmap.Save` is throwing, not the `Thread.Start`, actually.

Comment: From that message it seems to be trying to call a different overload than you are intending to call.

Comment: @Fildor but when trying to call ```System.Drawing.Size size = bitmap.Size;``` before ```bitmap.Save()``` I get the exact same error message. Now I did try the whole thing with a global field and not ```ParameterizedThreadStart``` in hopes of getting it to run. But then I get a ```object in use``` exception.

Comment: That"s really weird. What happens in the "backend" before it raises the event?

Comment: Looks like some kind of camera or video capture library.  The *very* common default behavior of such a library is that the bitmaps it generates are only valid while the ImageReceived event fires.  Necessarily so, it generates too many bitmaps to be able to keep them valid, memory usage would quickly explode.  In other words, you can't store the bitmap or use it later, after the event handler returned.  Unless you make a copy yourself, which the code already does btw, you'll have to give up on the thread.

Comment: Sounds like there's a threading issue here. `Bitmap` is not threadsafe because it's a GDI object. You need to either create and use on the same thread, or marshal all calls back to the original thread using `Invoke` or similar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Bitmap threadsafe for readonly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23495701/is-bitmap-threadsafe-for-readonly)

Comment: @Charlieface how would I go on about using the original ```Thread```? My first idea was to simply add the code ```Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { bitmap = parameter as Bitmap; });``` to the ```ProcessImage``` method. Unsurprisingly that did not work.

Comment: @Charlieface never mind. I think I found a solution to my problem.

Comment: No you need to create the actual bitmap on that thread. If you have an answer feel free to answer your own question below

Answer (score 0):

After searching for quite some time this is what I came up with. It might not be ideal but it works in my case:

```cs
private void StartBtn_Click()
{
    //is another class which accesses the stream of an external camera
    backEnd = new BackEnd();

    backEnd.ImageReceived += backEnd_ImageReceived;

    if (backEnd.Start())
    {
        hasError = false;
    }
    else
    {
        hasError = true;
    }
}

//is called when backEnd gets an image
private void backEnd_ImageReceived(object sender, Bitmap bitmap)
{
    try
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        bitmap.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        BitmapImage bitmapimage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapimage.BeginInit();
        bitmapimage.StreamSource = memoryStream;
        bitmapimage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmapimage.EndInit();
        bitmapimage.Freeze();

        if (_otherThread == null)
        {
            _otherThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ProcessImage));
            _otherThread.Start(ImageToByteArray(bitmap));
        }
        else if (!_otherThread.IsAlive)
        {
            _otherThread.Start(ImageToByteArray(bitmap));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("--- [MainWindow] Exception: " + e.Message);
        backEnd_MessageBoxTrigger(this, "Exception", e.Message);
    }
}

//this method could take longer that's why I'm using a second thread
private void ProcessImage(object parameter)
{
    if (parameter.GetType() == typeof(byte[]))
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = ByteArrayToImage(parameter as byte[]);

        byte[] bytes;
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Throws invalid parameter exception
            bitmap.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
        ...
    }
}

public byte[] ImageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image image)
{
    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
    return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(image, typeof(byte[]));
}

public System.Drawing.Bitmap ByteArrayToImage(byte[] bytes)
{
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(memoryStream);
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```